# Get current sub folder name in WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin, I want to get the `sub folder` name if wordpress is installed under a sub folder, e.g.

e.g.

```
http://blog.example.com/user1/archives/123 => user1
http://www.example.com/blogs/user1/archives/123 => blogs/user1
```

Are there any existing wordpress function I can extra the `sub folder` name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo parse_url(get_bloginfo('siteurl'),PHP_URL_PATH);?>
```